# Xdebug is started in the debug console but not working?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xampp, xdebug

Xdebug is not working despite `phpinfo()` is showing Xdebug section and in VS Code the red point is displayed and the control panel. Also the debug console is started as well.

[image]

[image]

I've tried to reinstall it again. I removed Apache and install XAMPP and then install Xdebug there.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently an issue with Xdebug 3.2 on Windows (specifically Apache) where it enables all features even when not requested. It is possible that this also affects other functionality like breakpoints. Until this is fixed, I recommend to use Xdebug 3.1.6, which you can still find on the [historical downloads page](https://xdebug.org/download/historical#3_1_6).

However, if you use `xdebug_info()` instead of `phpinfo()`, Xdebug will tell you what it tried to do (if anything at all) to connect to the debug client. There might be hints in there too.